# How To Overcome CORS Issue From Angular JS

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, cors

I got stuck at one point while calling REST service from my Angular JS code :

Service:

```
app.factory('UserFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/demoApp/service/users', {}, {
        show: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },       
    })
});
```

Controller:

```
function userListController($scope, UserFactory){   
    $scope.showUser = function () {
        alert("Show user ...");
        $scope.fetchedData = [];
        $scope.users = UserFactory.show();
        $scope.fetchedData.push($scope.users);

    };    
}
```

In order to overcome the CORS we have implemented Java CORS Filter as below -

```
Following line were written in doFilter method inside a Filter -

 response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

 response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");

 response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

 response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
```

It is working perfect with $http.jsonp.  But while we are calling with above way we got following error in Javascript console of the browser (Chrome) :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:8080/demoApp/service/users`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `http://localhost:63342` is therefore not allowed access.

Please help me ...

Regards,

Jayanta P.

Comment: You should allow CORS for you client domain on the server  http://tostring.it/2014/03/04/how-to-use-CORS-with-ASPNET-WebAPI-2/

Comment: $resource accepts using colon for parameters.  you should escape colon with \\:

Comment: Since your client and server are not running at same place, hence modern web browsers implement CORS. Are you sure you are applying `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", *);` at the correct place in server side?

Comment: I used this pre-built filter: http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html . The nice thing is that it is also available through Maven should you be using that. Quick setup and I've not had any problems yet.

Answer (score 1):

Very helpful. This excerpt:

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

worked very well; however, I had to disable the security flag of my Chrome browser by using the CORS plug-in available in Chrome. After that, I was able to make restful call from my angularjs app seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);
```